# Tool for generating UML class diagram from Doctrine annotations

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, metadata, tool-uml

I am looking for a tool that would generate an UML class diagram from Doctrine's @ORM annotations. Especially showing the relations between entities would be useful. Is there any such tool?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? I would also find this useful...

Comment: Unfortunately not yet, I will post here if I do find one or make my own tool.

Comment: I'm also interested in, let me know if you need help developing...

Comment: This post is closed, so I put a tool I wrote for this here: https://github.com/juanmf/Entities2Puml

Answer (score 8):

Try [ORM Designer](http://www.orm-designer.com/). You can import annotations and get the visual model. This model can be exported to PDF or PNG file.

In addition you can also edit your schema files visually, and then continuously export your definitions back to your code.

This is how model looks like:
[image: Example of ORM Designer model]

Comment: ORM Designer has new version called [Skipper](http://www.skipper18.com) . New version has a lot of new improvements and it's full native with Windows, OS X and Linux.

Answer (score 7):

This answer is framework-specific, but I'm working on adding support for this tool in `doctrine/common`, so if you are using symfony or CI or other frameworks, this may also be available soon.

If you are using [Zend Framework 2.1](https://github.com/zendframework/zf2/tree/release-2.1.3) (as I'm writing) and follow my [tutorial on installing Doctrine 2 ORM with ZF2](http://marco-pivetta.com/doctrine-orm-zf2-tutorial), the developer toolbar will give you the ability to generate a diagram of all the entities with their relations, as of following picture:

[image: UML diagram generated from Doctrine 2 ORM mappings via DoctrineModule]

The tool is not yet perfect, but you may find it and help improve it in [DoctrineORMModule](https://github.com/doctrine/DoctrineORMModule).